# Adding .animate that changes backgroundColor of a span inside link tag doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am trying to make the span class="term-name" be animated in a way in changes backgroundColor randomly from a set a predefined colors/hex

Here is the HTML tag.

```
    <ul id="filter" class="group">              
                <li>
                    <a class="art-direction" href="#" title="View all items filed under Art Direction">
                        <span class="term-name">Art Direction</span>

                        <!-- START .term-count -->
                        <span class="term-count">4<span class="triangle-down"></span></span>
                        <!-- END .term-count -->

                    </a>
                </li>


                <li>
                    <a class="brand-strategy" href="#" title="View all items filed under Brand Strategy">

                        <span class="term-name">Brand Strategy</span>

                        <!-- START .term-count -->
                        <span class="term-count">2<span class="triangle-down"></span></span>
                        <!-- END .term-count -->

                    </a>
                </li>


                <li>
                    <a class="communication-2" href="#" title="View all items filed under Communication">

                        <span class="term-name">Communication</span>

                        <!-- START .term-count -->
                        <span class="term-count">5<span class="triangle-down"></span></span>
                        <!-- END .term-count -->

                    </a>
                </li>


                <li>
                    <a class="design-collaboration" href="#" title="View all items filed under Design Collaboration">

                        <span class="term-name">Design Collaboration</span>

                        <!-- START .term-count -->
                        <span class="term-count">2<span class="triangle-down"></span></span>
                        <!-- END .term-count -->

                    </a>
                </li>



    </ul>
```

And this is the JS code I made, it doesn't work. It is supposed to put a random background color to the span when I am hovering it.

```
$( '#filter a' ).hover( function() {
//Store available css classes
var classes = new Array("green", "purple", "teal", "violet", "pink");

//Give a random class index
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length);
    $(this).find( '.term-name' ).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: 'classes[randomNumber]',}, 500, 'easeInOutExpo');

}, function() {
    //return to original
    $(this).find( '.term-name' ).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: 'white',}, 500, 'easeInOutExpo')";

});
```

It was inspired by the JS code (http://jsfiddle.net/GNgjZ/290/)

Btw, as you can observe the link is composed of 2 span (term-name & term-count)

```
    <a><span class="term-name"></span><span class="term-count"></span></a>
```

The term-count has also animate working and it is working, here is the JS:

```
    $( '.term-count' ).each( function() {
        $(this).css( 'marginLeft', '-' + Math.round( ($(this).outerWidth() / 2) ) + 'px' );
    });

    $( '#filter a' ).hover( function() {

        $(this).find( '.term-count' ).stop().animate({ marginBottom: '8px', opacity: 1 }, 500, 'easeInOutExpo');

    }, function() {

        $(this).find( '.term-count' ).stop().animate({ marginBottom: 0, opacity: 0 }, 500, 'easeInOutExpo');

    });
```

Thanks, Hope my JS works now.

Comment: You currently only have the hover background color set.  Do you want the background color to be set without hover?

Comment: Actually yes. If that means to return it to original backGround color after the hover. But, even the random color is not working.

Comment: Remove single quote of backgroundcolor's value i.e 'classes[randomNumber]' should be classes[randomNumber] since it is a variable

Comment: Still nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Hgtn5/) will get you off to a good start.  You had a number of things wrong with your code such as quotes around variables, extra semicolons and parentheses.  I recommend watching you console when you load your page and test your javascript.  It tells you a lot.  Look closely at the fiddle and let me know if you have any questions.  Hope this helps.

```
var classes = ["#1ace84", "#a262c0", "#4ac0aa", "#8c78ba", "#d529cd"];

$( '#filter a' ).hover( function(e) {

//Give a random class index
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length);
    $(e.currentTarget).find( '.term-name' ).css( "backgroundColor", classes[randomIndex]);

}, function(e) {
    //return to original
    $(e.currentTarget).find( '.term-name' ).css( "backgroundColor", 'white');
});
```

Comment: bro, you got any references where I can start learning these stuffs? I really really want to learn.

Comment: Check out codeacademy.com. They have some good free lessons. Also David crockford's "Javascript: The Good Parts" is a must read to learn how to use javascript well because not all of it is good. Also oreilley publishing puts about pocket guide books. They have one on javascript that will give you a good idea of what all the language has. Any time you decide to use a part of a library like jquery, read the documentation to learn how to use it properly. Finally, decide on something you want to build and build it and have fun with it!

Answer (score 1):

According to Jquery API, "All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used)". Apart from that your code has some other issues as well.